# Visual Studio clean cannot delete compiled Typescript files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

**Background**
In our VB.net/C# MVC solution we have just begun to use Typescript. To do so I set up a ScriptsTS directory that sits next to the Scripts directory where we would normally place our JS. I set up our tsconfig.json file so that the .ts files in ScriptsTS get compiled to their relative position in Scripts. We then check in this compiled js file because this is what we want published to our websites.

**Question**
When cleaning the solution it attempts to delete the compiled JS and by default that file is readonly if it's checked in so the clean fails. So my question is, how can I disable the deletion on clean? Or am I just doing this completely incorrectly and I should be using another process to handle these compiled files and not checking them in?

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es3",
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "assets/js/types" ],
    "outDir": "Scripts",
    "rootDir": "ScriptsTS"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "ScriptsTS/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your build artifacts shouldn't be in source control.

Comment: What do you suggest I do then? We are attempting to have as little additional dependencies on other tools as possible. We didn't really want to add in something like Grunt/Gulp to handle this. Also, those build artifacts are exactly what the published site needs, how would those files get there without being checked in?

Comment: How are you doing your deployments?

Comment: Using TFS to build and deploy with some custom scripts to copy the compiled application to various servers. There is no Typescript build step set up on the TFS server (2017) because we are in the process of migrating from XAML builds to the new build system.

Comment: Okay then, so this is a temporary arrangement while you 'upgrade' your build process.  Are you able to change your TFS workspace binding to local?  That should make it so VS doesn't use the readonly flag.

Comment: That seems unlikely as it's not something we could push down to our developers. You made it seem like this is something that could be accomplished using the new TFS2017 build process? How would that be done, via a Typescript compile build step? Maybe I could use that as leverage to upgrade faster.

Comment: Yes, you would use a TypeScript build step.  In the meantime, you can use a pre-build step to clear the readonly bit.  See the [Attrib build step](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#Attrib)

Comment: So what would that build step be? There is no task on the VNEXT build that allows TS to compile and it doesn't compile during the normal "Visual Studio Build" task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151525/discussion-between-jason-kaczmarsky-and-amy).